# Is there a word for "people who are computer illiterate"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Just as there is "computerate" to describe those who show familiarity with, and ability to use computers, is there a word to describe the opposite, those who are computer illiterate?

The word I'm looking for includes both those who have access to computers but, for some reason, choose to keep away from them, and those who can read and write but have never seen a computer in their entire lives.

I'm not looking for insulting or pejorative terms.

Comment: I know it apparently shows up in dictionaries, but despite that, I view *computerate* as *cute wordplay* and not as a serious word. In that vein I would probably coin *incomputerate*.

Comment: The use of the word "illiterate," as in "Joe Jones is computer illiterate (or a computer illiterate)" is unfortunate at best. Some of the most literate people in the world shy away from computers, and for good reason. Would you believe there are people (confession: I'm one of 'em) who still use a fountain pen to commit their thoughts to paper? For that reason, I prefer saying either a person is computer savvy or is not computer savvy. Enough of this unfortunate and inapt use of "illiterate" to refer to someone who's not computer savvy!

Comment: I have more than two degrees. Yet I consider myself computer illiterate to a great degree. I'm not ashamed of it, nor do I feel it's *unfortunate*. It just *is*. I see no particular reason to replace a well-understood phrase with a politically correct one.

Comment: It's interesting to note that, [according to dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/computer+literacy), the term _computer-literate_ was coined by Andrew Molnar, while director of the Office of Computing Activities at the NSF, who said, "We coined that phrase [in 1972]. It's sort of ironic. Nobody knows what computer literacy is. Nobody can define it. And the reason we selected [it] was because nobody could define it, and it was a broad enough term that you could get all of these programs together under one roof."

Comment: n00bs I believe, is the word for which you seek.

Comment: *Illiterate* defines total incomprehension, in my opinion. To use this in computing makes no sense to me, otherwise all previouse responders to this question that claim computer illiteracy are fooling themselves, as they managed to get here!

Comment: Something like `innumerate` that is used to describe people having problems with numbers (or basic math)? Well, `incomputerate` has already been suggested, but it doesn't feel quite as natural a word :-/

Comment: @medica: The devil's in the details. I said the USE of the term is unfortunate, not the person who doesn't mind admitting he or she is computer "illiterate." Big difference. Believe it or not, I am not big on political correctness. In fact, I kind of resist being PC, contrary as I am by nature and practice. If anything, I guess you could say I strive to be precise in my speaking and writing. (Notice: I say "strive to be precise," not "am precise.") No offense taken, by the way. Don

Comment: @rhetorician - thanks; I meant no offense. Computer savvy is a good way to describe people who know their way around a computer. But there's no good antonym. I really don't find it offensive myself, for myself. I don't call anyone else *computer illiterate* because I'm worse than anyone I know! My kids may laugh at my lack of computer skills, but they always come to me for medical advice. ') And I'm the resident biologist. So I'm good. :-)

Comment: MW indicates that this is not the only usage: '_illiterate_: having or showing a lack of knowledge about a particular subject'. And from Collins: '_lack_: something that is required but is absent or in short supply'. Though I disown the downvote.

Comment: Avoid "computerate". I've never heard it and my *computer* spellcheck does not acknowledge it. You could better phrase it "computer-illiterate people" or even "the computer-illiterate".

Comment: Computer illiterate is the answer, see [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=computer+challenged%2Ccomputer+neophytes%2Ccomputer+neophyte%2C+computer+illiterate&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomputer%20challenged%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomputer%20neophytes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomputer%20neophyte%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomputer%20illiterate%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I don't think we seek "for" something. I've never used a preposition after seek.

Comment: @Luis ***Seek for** the Sword that was broken: / In Imladris it dwells; / There shall be counsels  taken. / Stronger than Morgûl-spells.*

Comment: You seem to be getting quite a few negative terms as answers: things like *Luddite, cyberphobia, technophobe, troglodite*, and *lamer* — just to name a few that range from pejorative to insulting in the extreme. Are you looking for positive terms, negative terms, or neutral terms — or does that aspect not matter to you for the purpose of this question?

Comment: @tchrist  Thanks for the cue.  It does matter and I've re-edited the question saying I'm not looking for insulting or pejorative terms.  As for positive terms, humm... can there be a positive term for lack of knowledge or inability ?

Comment: @Luis Thanks, that was a good edit. In answer to your question about whether there can ever be a positive term for lack of knowledge or ability, there indeed can be. For just a few examples, it would not be hard to come up with positive words for a person who doesn’t know how sausage is made, or who doesn’t know how to kill a man in an undetectable fashion, or who doesn’t know what it feels like to sneak behind his parents’ or his spouse’s back, or who doesn’t know what human bodies look and smell like after a few months exposed to the elements. That sort of thing.

Comment: @tchrist: Now come up with positive ONE-word term for your example. I believe if we invent a ONE-WORD term meaning a LACK of something, then the word has typically negative connotation. I am very curious how you are going to back up your statement "it would not be hard to come up with positive words for..."

Comment: https://www.powerthesaurus.org/nerd/antonyms

Comment: @anongoodnurse Unless you are using someone as a scribe you can't be computer-illiterate, you are a contributer to Stack Exchange so you must have access to and the ability to use a computer, and you must also be able to navigate the internet. Just because you have no interest or skills in software or hardware doesn't make you computer-illiterate any more than an inability to make paper and pens, mix ink or typeset makes you conventionally illiterate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Computer illiterate* may be the best phrase for itself, but if something less potentially pejorative is wanted, perhaps ***novice*** would suffice, as in ***novice computer user*** or ***computer novice***.

nov·ice noun \ˈnä-vəs\
: a person who has just started learning or doing something

: a new member of a religious group who is preparing to become a nun or a monk

Note: I included the second definition as a comment on the sensibilities involved in mastering various levels of information and computer technology.

Comment: I don't think there is a great term but both computer illiterate and novice are probably the most commonly heard.

Answer (score 7):

[***computer-challenged***](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=FJJ5AEMd2HsC&pg=PA128&lpg=PA128&dq=%22computer-challenged%22+%22new+york+times%22&source=bl&ots=vPVLTi1zyP&sig=8CgsRsPYgIfn6dSK9uP1kkpdsuM&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=nmeSU7SCGOuA7QaXi4GYBA&ved=0CEsQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22computer-challenged%22%20%22new%20york%20times%22&f=false) is something that I already heard.

Alternately, consider [***computer neophyte***](http://www.nytimes.com/2004/03/25/technology/circuits/25beld.html).

> [neophyte](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/neophyte?show=0&t=1402150281): a person who is just starting out in a field of activity: *a neophyte in snowboarding*

Comment: Why is this so rated? I would assume anyone using either of these to be of foreign tongue, translating literally from a common term in their home country. These are absurd suggestions.

Comment: @OllieFord [...] https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=computer+challenged%2Ccomputer+neophytes%2Ccomputer+neophyte&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomputer%20challenged%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomputer%20neophytes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomputer%20neophyte%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I like that you stopped the chart before the rapid decline. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=computer+challenged%2Ccomputer+neophytes%2Ccomputer+neophyte&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomputer%20challenged%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomputer%20neophytes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomputer%20neophyte%3B%2Cc0 Note also nothing for BE, and that "computer illiterate" has around 17x the mentions..

Comment: @OllieFord Touché! Still and all, OP is looking for an alternative to "computer illiterate." Sorry if my answer seems to you so way off what he's asking.

Comment: "Computer challenged" - you must be kidding! Our civilization will end up due to the correctness and euphemisms! It sadly reminds of Soft Language by George Carlin - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h67k9eEw9AY

Comment: @OllieFord it's American habit to have X-challenged people (obligation for home of political correctness I presume). What's your basis for assuming computer-challenged to be taken from some other language (your "of foreign tongue, translating literally")? No language I know but English (American) likes the "X-challenged" concept.

Answer (score 4):

Chances are if a person in a first world country is still computer illiterate at this stage it is because they are in some way afraid or **intimidated** by learning the technology so **[technophobe](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/technophobe)** *might* fit the bill.

Comment: This is making a totally unfounded assumption on the reason for lack of familiarity with digital devices. Someone with a passion for technology might very well have no interest for modern digital devices exactly because they virtually exclude any possibility for a hands-on contact with the underlying technology. (Not considering stroking a touch-screen as hands-on contact.)

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen - That is why I used soft words like 'chances are' and 'might'. I realise it isn't a direct hit. Most if not all the technically illiterate people I know are so because they feel like they don't know how to get in and feel intimidated by the amount of information they think they need to know in order to get on board. However, the person you describe is not technically illiterate or a technophobe, they just prefer older technology or prefer a different means of access.

Comment: @GenericJam   The world is much more than England, Western Europe and the U.S.  Many African, Asian and Latin American countries, including the one I live in, have poverty belts where people can read and write but have never seen a computer in their entire lives. You can't call them technophobes.  Nor can you say that they "prefer old technology".

Comment: @Luis I adjusted my answer. Also, as per previous comment I would view this term as a correlating term with computer illiterate not necessarily totally descriptive.

Comment: @Luis that scenario was not described in the question, hence all of these phoboa and choice related answers.

Answer (score 4):

If it's an intentional avoidance of technology, **Luddite** may fit nicely. It broadly means one who is opposed to especially technological change.  While it sometimes has a negative connotation, it can also be used quite lightly: "I'm such a Luddite I can't even turn on my computer without help."

Source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Luddite

Comment: I think this would definitely be pejorative (albeit perhaps in a jokey way) if used of other people.

Answer (score 3):

It would seem logical that computer illiteracy is a trait of the cyberphobic

[**Cyberphobia**](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enwiki/11596627) is an irrational fear of or aversion to computers, specifically, the fear and/or inability to learn new technologies

Comment: Anyone who lives in a poverty belt of an underdeveloped country and has never seen a computer in his whole life, is not computer literate.  Still, I wouldn't say he has an irrational aversion to, or is unable to learn how to use a computer.

Comment: @Luis There are plenty of quodlibetarian arguments but someone  who has never been exposed ≠ with cyberphobia's association

Comment: So what's the word for a rational fear of or aversion to computers?

Comment: I would argue your opening assumption is wholly invalid. Computer illiteracy describes people 'not good with' computers; you could be extremely proficient in the use of a computer, whilst also fearing it.

Comment: Given that the OP has amended his question to specify that he is not seeking a pejorative or insulting term,  you might consider whether you may wish to revise your answer. Or not.

Answer (score 2):

[**digilliterate**](http://www.diclib.com/cgi-bin/d1.cgi?base=amslang&page=showid&id=2494) is something I've occasionally seen used.

Comment: While I like this one in general, it has the problem that it's impossible to tell in spoken speech whether it's meant to be digi-literate or digi-illiterate.

Comment: Good point. And apparently it's hard to tell in written speech too: my link shows the different forms as "digiliterates", "digiliterately" and "digiliterateness".

Answer (score 1):

**Techno-peasants**

People who would, truly, ‘rather use a pitchfork’.

https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=a%20techno-peasant

ps in some cases, I might be one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think just unmodified "illiterate" would work. No need to bandy about the bush. There is no more excuse these days for being computer illiterate than book illiterate.

Comment: That shows no understanding of the word's construction; there's innumerate, too.

Answer (score 0):

In our project we call it *digital illiterate*.

In Dutch we have a word for it, by the way. *Digibeet* is a word play on *digitaal* (digital) and *analfabeet* (illiterate). In English the same would become *digiterate*. If you Google this word, you will find some references to it.

Comment: How does that work? You've completely replaced the not prefix – a pretty important part of the word – with "digi".

Answer (score -1):

The construct 'non-computerate' has been used in this context in [*recent publications*](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199916108.001.0001/acref-9780199916108-e-6469).

Keep in mind that 'computerate' is a 1980's attempt to popularise a contraction of 'computer-literate', which did not meet with overwhelming success (despite inclusion in the Collins English Dictionary).

When it comes to less synthetic options, one who is computer-illiterate by their own intent or desire might be described as a [*luddite*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/luddite). If they are instead willing users of computers, they might better be described as a [*novice*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/novice) or [*neophyte*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/neophyte), but none of these terms are specific to computer literacy.

Comment: People who have a dislike of technological progress, rather than a dislike of social progress, or humanity in general, can be more precisely called a [Luddite](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Luddite).

Comment: Inappropriate suggestion - totally different implications to describing somebody as "computer-illiterate".

Comment: Given that the OP has amended his question to specify that he is not seeking a pejorative or insulting term,  you might consider whether you may wish to revise your answer. Or not.

Answer (score -1):

In IT jargon we sometime use [lamer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamer).

> A lamer is widely understood to be the antithesis of a hacker. While a
>   hacker strives to understand the mechanisms behind what he or she
>   uses, even when such extended knowledge would have no practical value,
>   a lamer only cares to learn the bare minimum necessary to operate the
>   device in the way originally intended.

ADDED after the OP had added a limiting condition:

> I'm not looking for insulting or pejorative terms.

I guess you will hardly find any **single-word** term (in general, not only in connection with the computer literacy)  with a meaning "lack of something", especially "lack of knowledge", with *non-negative* connotation.

For the IT craft, any word meaning "computer illiterate" would be pejorative :) I cannot see any difference in connotation between *lamer* and *technophobe* or *digital illiterate* or *luddite* or *cyberphobic*.

Comment: Given that the OP has amended his question to specify that he is not seeking a pejorative or insulting term,  you might consider whether you may wish to revise your answer. Or not.

Comment: @tchrist: well, for the IT craft, any words meaning "computer illiterate" would be pejorative :) I cannot see any difference in connotation between "lamer" and "technophobe" or "digital illiterate" or "luddite" or "cyberphobic". "Computer novice" does not answer the OP's question at all, and "computer challenged" sadly reminds of Soft Language by George Carlin - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h67k9eEw9AY :( Why have you particularly chosen my answer as not correct? I cannot see it more or less incorrect than the other answers.